# How to replace +91 using regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, pattern-matching

Get from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_replace2

Now I want to change +91 in a string. From https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_replace2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace "blue" with "red" in the paragraph below:</p>

<p id="demo">Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/blue/g, "red");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Lets consider following string.

String:- Hi My number is +919090909090 and +9190820209282 and ... etc.

I want result like: Hi My number is +91 - 9090909090 and +91 - 90820209282 and ... etc.

But when I using regex pattern, it seems to through an error when I am using 
`str.replace(/blue/g, "red");`

> Invalid regular expression: /+91/: Nothing to repeat"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` sign is a special character in regex

> Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) (from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/))

It needs to be escaped if you want to match against the string literal `+`:

```
/\+91/
```

will match.

An example replacement like you want it to have would be (again from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/))

```js
const regex = /(\+91)/g;
const str = `+911147005555, +911147005556, +919999973703`;
const subst = `\$1 - `;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: If I use const str = `Substitution result:  +911147005555, +911147005556, +919999973703`; Then it will only replace  first +91 but I want all +91 to be replaced with +91 -

Comment: Hi @VIKASKOHLI. Then use the `g` modifier: const regex = /^(\+91)/g;

Comment: Not working with this. But I made a function which split into array then using loop to get the result and also concatenating myfinal result

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI oh sorry, didn't read the whole regex earlier. There's no function needed, I've updated my answer with the working regex for the multiple strings!

Comment: you changed /^(\+91)/g to /(\+91)/g? Why now this working with changing that ?

Comment: ^ indicates that the match should be at the start of the string, without that, it matches every occurrence @VIKASKOHLI

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.spacehypheninPhoneNumber = function () {

      const regex = /^(\+91)/;
      const strs = "+911147005555, +911147005556, +919999973703";
      const subst = "\$1 - ";
      const space = " ";
      var replaced = strs.replace(/ /g, '');
      var getAllNumbers = replaced.split(',');
      var finalResult = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < getAllNumbers.length; i++) {

          console.log('Substitution result: ', getAllNumbers[i]);
          const result = getAllNumbers[i].replace(regex, subst);

          console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
          if(i==0){
              finalResult += space+ result;
          }else{
               finalResult += ","+space+ result;
          }

      }
      console.log('Final Output that I want:'+finalResult );
  }
```

Its working fine. I am using the regex pattern which @baao told me. Then by using loop I concatenate the result